# undefined reference to 'get_int'

Tags: c, cs50

I'm using visual studio code on Window 10.

I extracted `cs50.h` and `cs50.c` and copied them to `C:\msys64\mingw64\include\`.

Now after running the code, I'm getting `undefined reference to 'get_int'` and  `Id returned 1 exit status`.

An online solution suggested:

> In your source code, change `#include <cs50.h>` to `#include <cs50.c>`

But I can't find any `<cs50.h>` in `cs50.c` source file, instead, it has `"cs50.h"`.

I'm not able to understand:

> How to link cs50 when compiling your code with clang, by using `-lcs50`

Comment: .h file are a header file that contains definition to include in other c or h file. .c file are the file that are to be compiled to generate object file that will then be linked to generate executsble program (.exe files on windows) so .h files in include is good. .c files must be in another dir.

Comment: You can only use `-lcs50` if you have installed the CS50 library or compiled the source code into a library. Otherwise you have to compile and link cs50.c with your project.

Comment: @Gerhardh, where I'll use `-lcs50`?. I just installed `vs code` & `cs50 library` in `Ubuntu` as well

Comment: Are you asking about Windows or Ubuntu now? If you have installed the library in Ubuntu, you can use `-lcs50` as last option in your compiler command.

Comment: @Gerhardh, `compiler command?` there is a `terminal window` in Ubuntu.

Comment: I assume you mean your shell window. What command do you enter to compile your code?

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm using an extension in vs code `code runner`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't do (1).  It is poor advice. Also by asking questions about solutions you are turning it into an X-Y problem.  You would do well to delete everything after the second paragraph.  And you should post the entire build log, not just the final error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you haven't compiled the library first. Here's how to do it:

##### 1. Download the Library Files:

Download the latest version of the cs50 library header (`cs50.h`) and source (`cs50.c`) files from this URL: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/main/src. Make sure both files are placed in the same directory.

##### 2. Compile the Source Code:

Compile the `cs50.c` file using the following command (ensure both `cs50.h` and `cs50.c` are in the same directory):

```bash
gcc -c cs50.c
```

This command creates a compiled object file named `cs50.o` in the same directory.

##### 3. Create the Static Library:

Use the `ar` (GNU Binutils) tool to create an archive static library file.  In Windows, MinGW compilers typically have `ar` installed by default.

```bash
ar rcs libcs50.a cs50.o
```

This command creates a static library file named `libcs50.a`.

**Note:** You can now delete the `cs50.o` file as it's no longer needed.

##### 4. Create a Test Program File (test.c):

Create a `test.c` file to test if the library works properly:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    string str = get_string("What is your name?: ");
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

##### 5. Organize File Structure (Optional):

For better organization, you can create a specific directory structure to manage the library files:

```bash
.
├── include
│   └── cs50.h
├── lib
│   └── libcs50.a
└── test.c
```

Copy the `cs50.h` header file to the `include` directory.
Move the static library `libcs50.a` to the `lib` directory.

##### 6. Compile the Test Program:

Compile the `test.c` source code with the following command:

```c
gcc -I./include -L./lib test.c -o test -lcs50
```

**Explanation of flags:**

- **`-I./include`:** Specifies the directory containing the header files (here, `./include`).
- **`-L./lib`:** Specifies the directory containing the libraries (here, `./lib`).
- **`test.c`**: The source code file to compile.
- **`-o test`:** Sets the output executable file name to `test`.
- **`-lcs50`:** Links the program with the static library `libcs50.a`.

##### 7. Execute the Test Program:

Once compiled, you can run the test program by simply typing its name in the terminal:

```bash
./test
```

This will prompt you for your name and then print it back to the console.

**Example Output:**

```bash
What is your name?: World
Hello, World!
```

##### Refarance:

You can watch this YouTube video for more information: https://youtu.be/m6RVY84_mQE